# Java - BankAccount.class

Tags: java, methods

Now, I know this isn't the BankAccount.class, but it's similar to it, and I'm having problems with the final part. It's for an assignment at my college and I just need someone to point me in the right direction on what to next. I've done the first part, but I need someone to explain how to print records using PersonTester.

```
public class Person {

private String forename;
private String surname;
private int age;
private double height;
private String gender;

public void setForename(String x)
{
    forename = x;
}

public String getForename()
{
    return forename;
}

public void setSurname(String x)
{
    surname = x;
}

public String getSurname()
{
    return surname;
}

public void setAge(int x)
{
    age = x;
}

public int getAge()
{
    return age;
}

public void setHeight(double x)
{
    height = x;
}

public double getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public void setGender(String x)
{
    gender = x;
}

public String getGender()
{
    return gender;
}}
```

And now the tester class:

```
public class PersonTester {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

}}
```

Thanks for the help in advance, it's quite late where I live now, so it may take a some time for me to reply if I have anymore problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Person` class that you have written, you can set the values to attributes and print them using get methods.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setForename("Elizabeth");
String forename = p.getForename();
System.out.println("Forename: " + forename);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is the system.out.println() method, I am going to assume that you haven't used it before.

I will try not to give you exactly what would go into your PersonTester class, but a series of examples that will definitely help you:

```
system.out.println("Hello World"); // "Hello World" is printed (without quotations)
```

For the following examples, lets assume that the Person p's surname was set to be Brown. In other words, getSurname() would return the string "Brown".

```
system.out.println(p.getSurname());
/* Prints "Brown" (without quotations). */
```

The last concept you will probably need is concatenation, or the + symbol. Simply put, it joins strings together:

```
system.out.println("P's surname is " + p.getSurname() + ", nice to meet you.");
/* Prints "My surname is Brown, nice to meet you." (without quotations). */
```

Hopefully these few examples help you out.